# Word Wrapping forcing element to max-width

Tags: html, word-wrap, css

I have the following markup (well, a repro case for the real markup):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wrapping Woes</title>
    <style>
      .button {
        border: 1px solid black;
        background: #CCFFCC;
        min-width: 40px;
        max-width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      .button:hover {
        background: #CCCCFF;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>          
    <span class="button">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </span>
    <span class="button">
      Dolor
    </span>   
    <span class="button">
      Set Amet
    </span>  
</body>
</html>
```

The button contents are generated and unknown.  My problem is primarily with the "Lorem Ipsum" button - despite it wrapping, it is still taking up the full max-width (80px), when ideally I'd like it to shrink down to the width of the word.  This is actually the behaviour in IE7 Standards Mode, but it seems not so in IE8 mode or any standards compliant browser.

I tried `width: 1px;` but that causes the "Set Amet" to wrap as well.

How can I make the element width dependant on the wrapped text, not the pre-wrapped text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing some server-side wrapping. I only wanted wrapping to a maximum of 2 lines anyway, so manually putting a line break in the mark up produced the results required. Doesn't seem possible in css only.

Basically, I replaced the middle-most space with a new line if the text was more than 12 characters. Not perfect, but it works well enough.